# Security of WinVerifyTrust, or verifying trust of a locked file

Tags: windows, authenticode

I have a process that loads an external DLL (sort of a plugin system) where I want to verify that the loaded DLL is signed correctly using Authenticode. After perusing the documentation for [WinVerifyTrust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and friends) one thing that struck me as significant is that both operations work from a file path to the DLL.

It looks to me that its quite feasible to exploit this to cause my program to load an unsigned DLL, by presenting the program with a signed DLL, causing `WinVerifyTrust()` to succeed and immediately replacing the DLL with unsigned code before the `LoadLibrary()` call gets executed (this is a hard race condition, but it can be better controlled if the attacker has some control on the file system, for example when using a networked file system).

The API for `WinVerifyTrust()` seems to suggest that I can run the verification process on a handle to an open file. If I can open the file, verify the open file handle and then load the library from the same file handle - then I will be safe. Unfortunately `LoadLibraryEx()` - which would have been my prime suspect for implementing this - documents its `hFile` parameter as "reserved for future use".

My Next avenue of thought was to load the file contents into memory and then load the DLL from the memory, and I found the library [MemoryModule](https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule) that does this. I was wondering if there is some existing implementation that already goes and combines all this and allows the developer to securely verify and load a DLL, meaning I won't have to write it and maintain it myself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a random thought which I haven't tried: Can you open a `HANDLE` to the DLL with `FILE_SHARE_READ & ~( FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE )`, perform `WinVerifyTrust()` and `LoadLibrary()` **prior** to calling `CloseHandle()`? This would prevent the module from being replaced in between those two calls.

Comment: Why do you need `~(FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ)` as the default share permissions are `0` (i.e., no other share rights are granted)? Specifically, the `~` operator will enabled other bits that I may or may not want to have on. Anyway, I tried `CreateFile(path,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);` and it seems to do what I want. If you want to submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.